# How to troubleshoot periodically CPU jump in redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I use AWS ElastiCache Redis for our prod. I see CPU every 30 minutes of the round hour from average of 2-3% to 20%.
This is constant, which tells me it comes from schedule job.

From cloudwatch I have a suspicion it is related to `KEY` (and maybe `SET`) commands and it's latency is the only one which jumps in the same exact time as the CPU jumps.
I would like to understand what `KEY` (and maybe `SET`) commands run on a specific time, or some other way which can help me investigate this.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

with `redis-cli monitor` I was able to get most of the commands running on server in a stream and get the high usage.